# Crystal Report: Multiple column and multiple rows

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a long list like this:

```
  list item 1<br/>
  list item 2<br/>
  list item 3<br/>
  list item 4<br/>
  list item 5<br/>
  list item 6<br/>
  list item 7<br/>
  list item 8<br/>
  list item 9<br/>
  ....<br/>
  list item 100<br/>
```

I want to crystal report to display it like a table grid layout, like this:

> list item
>   1        list item 6
>   list item 2        list item
>   7
>    list item
>   3        list item 8
>   list item 4        list item
>   9
>    list item
>   5        list item 10
>   
>    list item 11       list
>   item 16
>    list item
>   12       list item 17
>    list
>   item 13       list item 18
>   list item 14       list item
>   19
>    list item 15       list
>   item 20
>
> list item 21       list item
>   26
>   ...                     ...

**Question:**

How do I create it with Crystal Report? If Crystal Report can not do it, what other report tool can do it, SSRS or MSWord (mail merge), any others?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the `section expert`, select the `detail` section.

Check `Format With Multiple Columns`

Click on `Layout` tab

Change formatting to match what you want.

Comment: This resolved the two columns problem, thanks. But I want to do it like a grid layout, in one page I have 6 blocks layout in 2 columns and 3 rows, I want my long list to display in top left block first, then if the list does not end go to top right block, then if list not end go to middle left block, then middle right block, then bottom left, then bottom right.